# Django Model @property duplicates queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**Django model properties** is useful to access in run time, however this does not come without cost.

Below property cause huge duplicate queries due to database hit with each query **(product)**.

```
@property
def total_stock(self):
    """ SKU total stock """
    total = SKU.objects.filter(
        product=self
    ).values_list("stock").aggregate(Sum(F("stock"))).get("stock__sum") or 0
    return total
```

**Any thought how to use django model @property in efficient way?**

Comment: Use annotate instead in query and forget about using properties in this manner. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: use [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) form `django.utils.functional` this will save the query result for next time.

Comment: Using cached property wont stop duplicated queries. Imagine i’m running for loop for each product and getting total stock.

Comment: @YousefAlm did solved the problem . i am also facing this problem .

Comment: you can use this in your view queryset.prefetch_related('purchase_entries').annotate(total_count=Sum('purchase_entries__unit_price'))